# Logstash: send different json fields to different types in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following format of JSON data that I send to a logstash instance
listening on a http endpoint

```
{
    client: "c",
    pageInfo: ["a","b","c"],
    restInfo: ["r","s","t"]
}
```

My goal is to send this input to an elasticsearch endpoint as two different types in the same index; for example

```
 PUT elasticsearchhost:port/myindex/pageInfo  
       { client: "c", pageInfo: ["a","b","c"] }

 PUT elasticsearchhost:port/myindex/restInfo  
       { client: "c", restInfo: ["r","s","t"] }
```

I have tried with some **filters** in logstash (split, mutate, grok) but I cannot understand how to perform this very specific split or if I have to modify my configuration also in the output section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `clone` to clone the events and then modify the clones.

For example:

```
filter { 
  clone { clones => ["pageInfo", "restInfo" ]  }
  if [type]=="pageInfo" {
     mutate {
        remove_field => "restInfo"
     }
  }
  if [type] == "restInfo" {
     mutate {
        remove_field => "pageInfo"
     }
  }
}
```

And then on your `elasticsearch` output, be sure to include `document_type => "%{type}"`

Comment: thank you, it works! In this way it creates three entities related to the same event; is there a way to have just one clone and refer to the original message in the 'if' statement? what would the original type value be for the original message?

Comment: The type for the original event is whatever you set on input.

Comment: You can also do else if and then a final else {drop{}}